# How to generate a direct calling wrapper bytecode with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I use reflection in an Aspect Oriented Library project in C#. In some places, it gets slower. Then I read an article and it says "You can use reflection once in a speeded up way with generate a direct calling wrapper bytecode." What's the way to do this? What is unusual with this technic?

Comment: Could you link that article?

Comment: I read this in a book at my company. It was like how to build frameworks. When I search the words "direct calling wrapper bytecode", I found a comment in stackexchange as well. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123959  in the second comment someone was mentioned this technic as well.

Comment: That basically means writing your own highly optimized aspect oriented framework. I would not recommend that, your application will take much more time to load and I don't think you can achieve a significant performance boost. Do some profiling tests, see where the code gets slow.

Answer (score 1):

it just means you can always prepare delegate using reflection / generic / generated code to do the job instead of invoking & introspecting things in nominal way.

for exemple, imagine you have to write a method to serialize an object.

```
public class Serializer<T>
{
    void Serialize(Stream stream, T value)
    {
        if (object.Equals(value, null)) { return; }
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(int)) { ... return ; }
        if (type == typeof(string)) { ... return; }
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(value);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

this implementation use a lot of reflection in each call and can be changed by

```
public class Serializer<T>
{
    static private readonly Action<Stream, T> m_Serialize;

    static Serializer()
    {
        Serializer<T>.m_Serialize = Expression.Lambda<Action<Stream, T>>(... [a lot of reflection here] ...).Compile();
    }

    public void Serialize(Stream stream, T value)
    {
        Serializer<T>.Serialize(stream, value);
    }
}
```

Reflection is used to create delegate using linq expression (in this case) and will hit only once.